# Referencing master file with rmarkdown (knitr)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a parent which includes a child file, and I'd like to compile the parent file, when I press Cmd+shift+k (I'm using rstudio). I know in latex you can reference a master file by writing a line of code at the top of your child file. I was wondering if you could do something similar with rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1):

In R Markdown it works like this:

````
---
title: "parent"
output: pdf_document
---

This is the title page

```{r child='child1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child='child2.Rmd'}
```
````

The child `.Rmd` files are in the same folder in this example.

You do not need to specify a YAML header in the child `.Rmd`'s

Answer (score 0):

The [knitr /demo/child/ page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/) has an overview on how to do this.

If that's not informative enough, you can check out the [`knitr` section](https://github.com/stevenpollack/ucbthesis#knitr) of a thesis template repo's README.

Finally, you can see the parent-child model in action over in https://github.com/stevenpollack/masters_thesis/blob/master/masters_thesis.Rnw. A stripped down version of that link would be:

```
\documentclass[masters]{ucbthesis}

\begin{document}

<<abstract, child='abstract.Rnw'>>=
@

<<introduction, child='introduction.Rnw'>>=
@

<<adaboostToBoost, child='boosting_methodology.Rnw'>>=
@

<<boostrImplementation, child='boostr_implementation.Rnw'>>=
@

<<discussion, child='summary_and_future_work.Rnw'>>=
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tried adding a chuck where I use set_parent, but it doesn't seems to work. Does it work when you using rmarkdown?